# How to Migrate T-SQL Stored procedure to Postgres DB of version prior to 11

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to migrate T-SQL Stored procedure to Postgres database of version prior to 11, in any way? I know CREATE PROCEDURE supported  from Postgres V 11 and above. Is there any other way we can achieve the same thing as we do in T-SQL Stored Procedure. We are planning to move to Amazon Aurora which supports Postgress 10.6 now. I am new to Postgres. Any suggestion would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Unsurprisingly, it depends on what you are trying to do.  For most things, you will be able to use functions instead of procedures.  If your stored procedures require transaction management, though, you won't be able to do that without procedures.